# Toggle between selected classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I find my self doing this a lot:

```
$(document).on("click","li",function(){
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected"); // Remove any old selected
    $(this).addClass("selected"); // Apply selected to this element
});
```

Is there a better and less repetitive way of doing a task like this? Like toggle a class. Btw, only one element can be selected at a given time.

Thanks.

Comment: Does [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) do what you need?

Comment: It's a code-review, by the looks of it, rather than the code not working.

Comment: @ChrisDixon Code is working but inneficantly, Lots of user ask for alternitives to specific methods.

Comment: @stuartd No, Id be just replaceing removeClass() with toggleClass()

Comment: Your code is fine, toggleClass won't work because you have the single selected rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debating with Jack I propose mine.
Assuming your list is here :

```
var $myList = $('#list');
```

Then:

```
$myList.on("click","li",function(){
    $(".selected",$myList).removeClass("selected"); // Remove any old selected
    $(this).addClass("selected"); // Apply selected to this element
});
```

or

```
$myList.on("click","li",function(){
    $(this).siblings(".selected").removeClass("selected"); // Remove any old selected
    $(this).addClass("selected"); // Apply selected to this element
});
```

Your way of doing it is good enough for me but Jack's is faster and mine is in between both.
I like this one because you don't need to assume there will only be one `selected` element. And searching is faster when we provide context as far as I know

Answer (score 6):

A more efficient way is to keep track of the last selected item:

```
var $selected = null;

$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
    if ($selected) {
        $selected.removeClass('selected');
    }
    $selected = $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Of course, this should work as long as that particular function is the only one that will ever add / remove the `selected` class.

This could optionally be wrapped inside a closure to remove the `$selected` variable.

Btw, using `document` as the anchor for your delegation isn't best practice. It's better to choose the nearest node that will not get removed from the document.

**Update**

As [Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568971/toggle-between-selected-classes#comment23807041_16569125), you could eliminate the branch like so:

```
var $selected = $();

$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
    $selected.removeClass('selected');
    $selected = $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

The ability to use `$()` was introduced in 1.4; before that you would use `$([])`.

Comment: You could also do `var $selected = $([])` and remove the if statement.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks! In more recent versions of jQuery, `$()` would also work.

Comment: I find the OP solution more secure imo

Comment: @TecHunter I'm not sure what you mean by more secure. The answer is clear about the conditions under which it works.

Comment: @Jack it's just that, the OP way will definitely remove class from all other elements while yours assume they will never be more than one selected element. I'm not saying this case will happen but it is possible.

Comment: @TecHunter that's exactly the precondition of my answer, so it's more of a fact than an opinion :)

Comment: @Jack haaaaa true didn't see the line the first time I've read your post, my bad :) but it still is my opinion, I prefer to not trust precondition :p

Comment: @TecHunter Then you prefer to write suboptimal code :) jokes aside, with this precondition eliminated the logical next choice is to cache `$('.selected')`; but doing so introduces another precondition, one that won't work well with dynamically added elements unless you write more management code or ... use OP's code :)

Comment: @Jack exactly, no cache, no management, just DOM checking. I would just propose a small modification to OP code, instead of `$('.selected')` I would do `$('.selected', myListWithOneOption)`. Faster searching less 'suboptimal'

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(this).on("click", "li", function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Note: This works only if `<li>`s aren't being dynamically added, and if they're all siblings.  (Common case, but not the only possible one.)

Comment: `<ul><li>one item</ul> <ul><li>another item, not a sibling</ul>` breaks too, though.  It depends on what the HTML will look like.

Comment: @cHao Why are you focusing on that? It has nothing to do with the question, **and** it's the code the OP is using. It's an example, the HTML isn't important.

Comment: Unless *all* siblings are selected, this is quite inefficient without a cache; selecting them inside, albeit short and all, is not a good idea.

Comment: @Ian: It has quite a bit to do with the question, actually.  I'm focusing on it because *this code breaks in ways the OP's code doesn't.*  Whether it works depends much more on the structure of the document (specifically, where all the `<li>`s are) at the time an `<li>` is clicked.

Comment: @cHao this would work okay for dynamically added items too, because `.siblings()` is calculated each time.

Comment: @Jack: It would work if all of the items are in the same list.  I didn't see that specified, though.

Comment: @cHao I see what you're saying. I must not have read that correctly, because that makes perfect sense. This works assuming the "selected" class should be applied to each group of sibling `<li>`s

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about this, you could keep your list elements in a variable, such as:

```
var $liElements = $('#yourContainer > li');

$(document).on("click","li",function(){
    $liElements.not($(this)).removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: The cache is a good touch, but won't work when the items are dynamically added.

Comment: Very true, but could be updated when items are dynamically added in the event handler, every little helps.

Comment: As far as the cache goes, `var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');`.  The return value is live, meaning any `<li>`s that get added to the document will magically appear in the list as well.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of keeping track of the current element is the same as the other answers, but you can wrap this logic up cleanly in a function such as

```
function class_swapper=function(cls){
    var cur;
    return function(elt){
        if (cur) { cur.classList.remove(cls); }
        elt.classList.add(cls);
        cur=elt;
    };
};
```

A call to `class_swapper` returns a function used to actually apply the specified class to a particular element (and remove it from the previous one, which is remembered inside the function). You can use this as follows:

```
var swapper=class_swapper("selected");
swapper(elt1);
swapper(elt2);
```

or in terms of your example

```
$(document).on("click","li",function(){swapper(this);});
```

I've used `classList.add` and `classList.remove`, which is a classy way (ouch) of manipulating classes in modern browsers, but of course these could be replaced by jQuery's `addClass` etc. as necessary.

Comment: I like the idea of encapsulating this, and it should work even with dynamically added elements, as long as you only have one group to toggle like this.  Style note, though: insanely abbreviated variable names suck.  :P

Comment: Is there a way to do it like $(..).swapClasses(..) ?

Comment: @Jessica yeah, you should do a jQuery plugin. check it out here http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/writing-your-own-jquery-plugins